# Examples of real-world data that takes values in a separable Hilbert space

Tags: statistics, applications, data-analysis

I'm looking for some examples of real-world sample-data (not actual data-samples but rather scenarios) where each observation takes values in a non-Euclidean separable Hilbert space.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated, and the bounty will be awarded to the most interesting example(s) where testing paired sample-data for independence could be of interest.